# How to install a plugin from github in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio-2015, cordova-plugins

I need to install a plugin from GitHub to my Visual studio 2015 project. In VS2015, we have option to clone, create git repo, however there is no option to install a plugin from github.
Any idea?

The plugin I am trying to install is available at https://github.com/brodysoft/Cordova-SQLitePlugin.git.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I was able to figure this out.
Open config.xml -> Go to Plugins -> Click on Custom -> Select Git and enter the URL.